# Passing Additional Parameters to WinMain

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am new to C++, trying to make bootstrapper for an executable. I wanted to send additional parameters along with lpCmdLine

```
typedef int (__cdecl *BooterMain_t)(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
```

I load the library

```
HMODULE Program = LoadLibraryExA(".\\bin\\program.dll", NULL, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH);
```

this is how I launch it

```
BooterMain_t procBooterMain = (BooterMain_t)GetProcAddress(Program,"BooterMain");
procBooterMain(hInstance, hPrevInstance, InternalParameters, nCmdShow);
```

May I know how to pass InternalParameters along with lpCmdline? Currently it seems to be ignored.

Edit: About Internal Parameters,

```
char InternalParameters[MAX_PATH] = {0};
_snprintf_s(InternalParameters, _TRUNCATE, "-verify -console");
```

Comment: This sounds like you're reinventing `rundll32`. Have a look at that. Anyway, if you control the DLL then you also control the name and signature of whatever function you want to use as startup function, and if you don't control the DLL, then you will have to make do with whatever is documented.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Unfortunately, I don't have control over the DLL. I tried appending lpCmdLine but it doesn't seem to accept long strings, just crashes.

Comment: How is `InternalParameters` defined?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I've edited the post, please check. It doesn't seem to accept long string, If I add few more keys, it crashes.